# Variable alias in struct that can be used by static member function

Tags: c++

Is it possible to alias a variable in a struct/class the same way you would alias a type or a namespace? Ideally, the following syntax would work

```
extern int x;

struct A
{
  using x_alias = x;

  static void foo(int* dst)
  {
    *dst = x_alias;
  }
};
```

One solution is to use

```
#define x_alias x
```

but I would rather have a C++ solution. If x was a compile-time constant, I could do

```
static constexpr int x_alias = x;
```

Or another potential solution is to use

```
static int x_alias;
```

And then define x_alias elsewhere, but this adds complexity when linking.

Comment: That isn’t possible; but: what’s your use-case? Why couldn’t this just be solved by a regular assignment? (Edit: I should say: it *is* possible, and regular initialisation is precisely how this is done).

Comment: `int x_alias = x;` doesn't work because foo is a static function. The context is x used to be a compile time constant, but this isn't the case anymore, so NathanOliver's suggestion would be the lowest effort change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use C++17, then you can use a static member variable and declare it as [`inline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) like

```
struct A
{
  static inline const int& x_alias = x;

  static void foo(int* dst)
  {
    *dst = x_alias;
  }
};
```

And now you don't have to worry about suppling an out of line definition or any linker issues as the compiler/linker will now handle that for you.

---

I used `const` here so you can't change the value of `x` using `x_alias`.  That can be removed if you want to allow it to change the value.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't possible, instead, you could use a Reference to that value:

```cpp
extern int x;

struct A
{
  int& x_alias = x;

  void foo(int* dst)
  {
    *dst = x_alias;
  }
};
```